# Converting a md5 hash byte array to a string

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

How can I convert the hashed result, which is a byte array, to a string?

```
byte[] bytePassword = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    byte[] byteHashedPassword = md5.ComputeHash(bytePassword);
}
```

I need to convert `byteHashedPassword` to a string.

Comment: MD5 is deprecated. It is inherently broken as it does not reach the standards of collision or preimage resistance. 
For passwords, it's better to use iterated key-derivation functions such as Argon2 or PDKDF2.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
   public static string ToHex(this byte[] bytes, bool upperCase)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length*2);

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            result.Append(bytes[i].ToString(upperCase ? "X2" : "x2"));

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

You can then call it as an extension method:

```
string hexString = byteArray.ToHex(false);
```

Comment: what is the significance of upper casing?

Comment: a matter of preference. That's why I added a parameter to my method, so the caller can choose

Comment: It's the difference between `c0de` and `C0DE`, that's all.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel when you already have `Convert.ToBase64String()`

Comment: oh ok, I thought there was more too it! how does your answer differ from Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)?

Comment: A Base64 string is shorter. It uses all letters of the alphabet, digits and a few punctuation characters, so it's not hexadecimal. Base64 uses 4 characters for 3 bytes, while a hex string uses 6 characters for 3 bytes.

Comment: @Eric: there are situations where Base64 is not a good choice because of the extra punctuation characters that are used (passing it in a URL for example)

Answer (score 70):

I always found this to be the most convenient:

```
string hashPassword = BitConverter.ToString(byteHashedPassword).Replace("-","");
```

For some odd reason BitConverter likes to put dashes between bytes, so the replace just removes them.

Update:
If you prefer "lowercase" hex, just do a .ToLower() and boom.

Do note that if you are doing this as a tight loop and many ops this could be expensive since there are at least two implicit string casts and resizes going on.

Comment: does the same as @PhilippeLeybaert solution, but in one-line.

Answer (score 31):

You can use `Convert.ToBase64String` and `Convert.FromBase64String` to easily convert byte arrays into strings.

Answer (score 23):

If you're in the 'Hex preference' camp you can do this. This is basically a minimal version of the answer by Philippe Leybaert.

```
string.Concat(hash.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")))
```

`B1DB2CC0BAEE67EA47CFAEDBF2D747DF`

Answer (score 10):

Well as it is a hash, it has possibly values that cannot be shown in a normal string, so the best bet is to convert it to Base64 encoded string.

```
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

and use

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64(s);
```

to get the bytes back.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you could use the string constructor that takes bytes and an encoding, but you'll likely get a difficult to manage string out of that since it could contain lots of fun characters (null bytes, newlines, control chars, etc)

The best way to do this would be to encode it with base 64 to get a nice string that's easy to work with:

```
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

And to go from that string back to a byte array:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I would add you can use the built-in methods (I'm using .NET 6.0):

- `Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);` (Others have already mentioned this)
- `Convert.ToHexString(hashBytes);`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested a Nuget package I created called **CryptoStringify** allows you to convert a string to a hashed string using a nice clean syntax, without having to play around with byte arrays:

```
using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    string strHashedPassword = md5.Hash(password);
}
```

It's an extension method on `HashAlgorithm` and `KeyedHashAlgorithm` so works on SHA1, HMACSHA1, SHA256 etc too.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/cryptostringify