# Using SHA-1 in .NET Core

Tags: c#, cryptography, asp.net-core, .net-core, sha1

I get strange results when hashing a string in dotnet core
I have found this similar question: [Computing SHA1 with ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363358/computing-sha1-with-asp-net-core)
and have found how to [convert a byte array to string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11654597/169714) in .net core

this is my code:

```
private static string CalculateSha1(string text)
{
    var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(65001); // utf-8 code page
    byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(text);

    var sha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();

    var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(buffer);

    return enc.GetString(hash);
}
```

and this is my test:

```
string test = "broodjepoep"; // forgive me

string shouldBe = "b2bc870e4ddf0e15486effd19026def2c8a54753"; // according to http://www.sha1-online.com/

string wouldBe = CalculateSha1(test);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(shouldBe.Equals(wouldBe));
```

output:

> ���M�Hn�ѐ&��ȥGS

[image]

I have the nuget package `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms` installed (v 4.3.0)

Also tried with `GetEncoding(0)` to get the sys default coding. Also did not work.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but SHA-1 is being deprecated (see e.g. https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2014/09/09/sha1-deprecation-what-you-need-to-know and https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/04/29/sha1-deprecation-roadmap, among others). If you need strong crypto, you should move away from SHA-1.

Comment: I know, but please tell that to the external service that I am using ;-) (Dutch bank)

Comment: The static `SHA512` class is supported in both .NET Core and .NET Framework. Go with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure how 'SHA-1 Online' represents your hash, buts since it's a hash, it can contain characters that can't be represented in a (UTF8) string. I think you're better off using `Convert.ToBase64String()` to easily represent the byte-array hash in a string:

```
var hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

To convert it back to a byte-array, use `Convert.FromBase64String()`:

```
var bytes =  Convert.FromBase64String(hashString);
```

Also see: [Converting a md5 hash byte array to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435695/converting-a-md5-hash-byte-array-to-a-string). Which shows there a multiple ways to represent hash in a string. For example, `hash.ToString("X")` will use a hexadecimal representation.

Kudos for `broodjepoep`, by the way. :-)

Comment: @JPHellemons I don't know what method 'SHA-1 Online' uses to convert the hash to a string, might be something else. It doesn't matter though, as long as the application know which format it is.

Comment: @JPHellemons: did you try `hash.ToString("X")`?

Answer (score 8):

Solution to the issue so far:

```
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(0);

byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(text);
var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
var hash = BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-","");
return hash;
```

Comment: Solution to the issue so far? @Henk Mollema answered this 22 nov 2016.